# Toggle iframe js function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have this js function:

```js
var iframeShowing = false;

async function show() {
 
    var iframe1 = document.getElementById('help-popup');
    iframe1.style.display = iframeShowing ? 'flex' : 'none';
    iframeShowing = !iframeShowing;

  
}
```

The problem is that I need to click 2 times to actually show the iframe and make it work properly. After I click 2 times, it works properly(every click shows and hides the iframe). Try it on the website and you'll understand.
This is the html code:

```html
<i class="fas fa-question-circle" id="questionmark" onclick="show();"  >
```

This is the current website: https://personal-website.krix12.repl.co/
The above mentioned function is called when the blurple question icon is clicked.
How can I make it work on the first click?

Comment: Swap the two last operands in the ternary.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [DOMTokenList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) to toggle between flex and none:

```js
function toggle() {
  var iframe1 = document.getElementById('help-popup');
  iframe1.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
iframe {
  display: flex;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div><i class="fas fa-question-circle" id="questionmark" onclick="toggle();">?</i></div>
<iframe id="help-popup" class="hide"></iframe>
```